# Linq 2 Entities bombs out with no exception depending on query construction method

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, linq-to-entities

If I run this query (building it seperately)

```
// To make the SearchShipment Shipment 'entity' load eagerly
ctx.ContextOptions.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;

var query = from s in ctx.Stuff
            select new
            {
                Id = s.Id,
                SearchShipment = s.Shipment
            };

if (searchType == ArrivalNo)
{
    query = query.Where(x => x.SearchShipment.Arrivals.FirstOrDefault().ArrivalId == arrivalNo);
}
```

When I attempt a query.ToList() it just bombs out (doesn't get to the return statement of the method) with no message or exception (app is still running) but returns focus to the browser when debugging in VS2010 and no results are displayed / returned by the calling method.

But If I construct the query in one statement it works fine and returns the 941 results I was expecting.

```
var query = from s in ctx.Stuff
            where s.Shipment.Arrivals.FirstOrDefault().ArrivalId == arrivalNo
            select new
            {
                Id = s.Id,
                SearchShipment = s.Shipment
            };
```

Now If I perform a query.ToList() it works fine?

Any ideas why? It's got me stumped! I know outer left joins are a bit tricky in LINQ but this is just plain daft behaviour!

**EDIT**: I will put the 'solution' here encase it catches out others that come this way looking for a solution:

Part of the query I didn't declare to yourselves because I thought it inconsequential was:

```
Dmg = from d in s.Damages
      select d.DamageType.Description + " [" + d.DamageCode.Trim() + "]"
```

It was actually this code that was making it work or not work depending on how it was constructed?!?!?!?!?!? (This code was always present, and caused an issue one way, but not the other?!?!?!?!?)

It was throwing a silent error which I only found when running the query in LINQPad (and it highlighted the d part of the above subquery)

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

However by changing this to use an explicit join the query now works fine with the construction in parts method:

```
Dmg = from d in s.Damages
      join dc in ctx.DamageTypes on d.DamageCode equals dc.Code
      select d != null ? dc.Description + " [" + dc.Code.Trim() + "]" : string.Empty
```

as the song goes, How Bizarre, How Bizarre.

P.S. Maybe there is some logic here which, given project time constraints I cannot fathom I do not know.

Comment: Since there is a lot of differences in L2E query translation (and bugs), what EF or EFC version are you on?

Comment: You are using the variable query twice and the object types are not the same which causes the exception.

Comment: @IvanStoev Version v4.0.30319

Comment: @jdweng Thanks, but I don't think that is the case, it's an often used method of constructing a query in parts... e.g. query = query.Where(x => x.CallOffNo == callOffNo); works fine

Comment: EF4, really? Man, that's too old, many bugs have been fixed till then. Most likely it wouldn't happen on latest EF6.1.3. If you seek for workaround, I would suggest not using `FirstOrDefault().Property == something` syntax, but `Any`, e.g. `x.SearchShipment.Arrivals.Any(y => y.ArrivalId == arrivalNo)`. Of course this is speculation and might not fix the issue which for me is apparently EF bug.

Comment: By the way, it cannot just "bomb out". Either it works or not, we're in a binary world. So if it doesn't work, there is an exception somewhere, you just don't see it (e.g because of `Task`s or something else).

Comment: If you let the debugger stop when the exception is thrown, what does it say? Of if that can't be done, if you put a try catch in your main(), what does the exception say?

Comment: The bizarre thing is there is no exception at all, it is also not run in a task/asynch etc.... see incoming edit... I found the real issue.

Comment: @IvanStoev Yup stuck on 4, you don't have to tell me about it!, I dream of VS2010 upgrade to VS2017 and EF4 to EF6! :D

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var query = from s in ctx.Stuff
                select new
                {
                    Id = s.Id,
                    SearchShipment = s.Shipment
                };
if (searchType == ArrivalNo)
{
   var query2 = from s in query
   where s.Shipment.Arrivals.FirstOrDefault().ArrivalId == arrivalNo
   select s;
   query = query2;
}
```